# Open New Form From Passed Form as Parameter vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Is it possible to open the form passed by sub as new form for example:
vb.net 2010 windows forms

```
Public Sub CheckMembership (byVal OpenFormName as form)

Using NewFormInstance as new OpenFormName
NewFormInstance.ShowDialog
End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't tried OpenformName.ShowDialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a new instance of the form passed into this method. You can just do:

```
Public Sub CheckMembership (byVal OpenFormName as form)
    OpenFormName.ShowDialog
End Sub
```

---

In case you want to open a new form every time, you don't need a parameter in your method. You can just do:

```
Public Sub CheckMembership()
    Dim OpenFormName As New YourFormClass
    OpenFormName.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok thanks, thats how im doing it now but out of habit i always do the above when i call a specific form so i know i am getting a new form withoutdata attached.  If this is the only way im ok with it

Comment: If you're passing a form, it makes sense to use it. Otherwise you could create a method without parameters and create a new instance of the form inside it and show it.

Comment: ok so since im not passing any data along with form just use opendialog.  question: does opendialog always open a new form persay?

Comment: `ShowDialog()` just shows a form as modal. You need to specify if you need a new form or not. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub CheckMembership (byval OpenFormName as form)

    OpenFormName.ShowDialog

End Sub
```